# Mocking class instances inside a Class

Tags: python, class, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I'm currently writing tests for a wsgi server I made. The server class at `__init__` constructor inits 2 instances of other classes as members. Lets say

```
def __init__(self):
  self.a = A()
  self.b = B()
```

During tests, how can I mock self.a and and self.b as mock classes I made for them instead of using A and B ?

```
#I use this if I want to mock the entire server class
@mock.patch('myproject.server.MyServerClass',autospec=True)
```

Comment: The attributes are on an *instance*; what is the path to that instance? `myproject.server.myserverclass_instance`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more python I write the more curious I am about situations like this.  My inclination is usually to introduce dependency injection and pass in the created A and B classes on the constructor.  This makes it easy to both see the external dependencies and change them up when i need.  But sometimes that is overkill.  Could you not just:

```
server = Server()
server.a = MockA()
server.b = MockB()
```

Comment: +1 for dependency injection. Pass the dependencies directly into `MyServerClass`, or pass an object that is capable of creating them on-demand. Both of these approaches provide a code seam at which a test double can be introduced.

Comment: Good idea, thank you, I think I will change the __init__ so it can receive the instances as parameters. I can then pass mocks to my server during tests.